# using grep as command line tool in r data.table fread() - incorrect result

Tags: r, grep, data.table, fread

**Hello**,

This is my first posting here. I use excellent R data.table package. I need to import a file without comment lines, but I don't see any option in fread() to get rid of comment lines which are spread across the file, not only at the beginning of the file. To simplify - the file test.txt consists of 4 lines, comment lines begin with "#":

```
#A
A   AA
A   A#A
#A
```

I import data with fread() and then get rid of comment lines with grep (^#); everything works.
There is also an option to use grep inside fread() as a command line call instead a single file name. (For the record, I working in Windows, thus I have grep.exe in my project folder.) Grep works with simple regular expressions as expected when I call it from R:

```
> system("grep # test.txt")
#A
A   A#A
#A
> system("grep ^# test.txt")
#A
#A
```

But it ignores the beginning of line command "^" when called as a system command inside fread() function:

```
> fread("grep # test.txt", sep = "\t", header = FALSE, fill = TRUE)
   V1  V2
1: #A    
2:  A A#A
3: #A

> fread("grep ^# test.txt", sep = "\t", header = FALSE, fill = TRUE)
   V1  V2
1: #A    
2:  A A#A
3: #A
```

Thus, grep.exe as well as grep() in R are working as expected, but grep.exe called from fread() ignores beginning of line command (didn't try other regex). What is wrong here?

Comment: If you're on windows, this seems to work: `fread('grep "^#" test.txt')`

Answer (score 0):

```
#I need to import a file without comment lines!!!
#this seems to work
> fread('grep -v "^#" test_Rem.txt')
   A  AA
1: A A#A
```